# Suppose R1 and R2 are relations on A and R1 ⊆ R2. Let S1 and S2 be the transitive closures of R1 and R2 respectively. Prove that S1 ⊆ S2.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

please check the following proof.

1. Suppose R1⊆ R2 and S1 and S2 are transitive closures of R1 & R2 respectively.
2. Suppose (x,y)∈S1 such that S1=∩F where F={T⊆A x A| R1⊆T and T is transitive}
3. case1:

3.1) Suppose (x,y)∈S1 and (x,y)∉R1 such that ∃z∈A((x,z)∈R1 ∧ (z,y)∈R1) because S1 is transitive.

3.2) because R1⊆T, (x,z)∈T and (z,y)∈T. since T is transitive (x,y)∈T and S1⊆T.

3.3) since R1⊆R2, then (x,z)∈R2 and (z,y)∈R2.

3.4) let S2=∩G where G={U⊆AxA| R2⊆U and U is transitive}

3.5) since R2⊆U, (x,z)∈U, (z,y)∈U, and U is transitive then (x,y)∈U.

3.6) since U is arbitrary, ∀U∈G((x,y)∈U) then (x,y)∈∩G=S2 or (x,y)∈S2

4. case2:

4.1) Suppose (x,y)∈R1 and (x,y)∈S1

4.2) since R1⊆R2 then (x,y)∈R2

4.3) since R2⊆S2 then (x,y)∈S2

5. Therefore, S1⊆S2.
   QED

Comment: I am reluctant to check all this, because there is a short and direct route: $S_1$ is by definition the intersection of all transitive relations on $A$ that contain $R_1$ as a subset. One of them is $S_2$, since it is transitive and contains $R_2$ (hence also $R_1$) as a subset. This allows the conclusion that $S_1\subseteq S_2$.

Comment: i appreciate your input since it made things clearer.

Comment: In case you still want to know: If $S$ is the transitive closure of $R$ and $xSy$, that doesn't necessarily mean that for some $z$ you have $xRz$ and $zRy$. The path could be longer (see step 3.1). This is of course the right place to start, but you need to prove this on its own.
 In 3.2, $T$ is used without having been introduced. In 3.5 $U$ is not introduced either (I know what you mean, but you can't write it like that).

Comment: @martin.koeberl sorry for the delayed response. i thought line 2 was enough introduction 3.2)? so is line 3.4) for 3.5)? if you don't mind, how should i properly introduce them? i'm really having difficulty writing it proper way. thank you!